# how to scroll with selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have here a challenge that I spent some time addressing.

Selenium tells me that it cannot click a link that is not visible, so that means I need to scroll my canvas? I am using ubuntu 10, firefox 3, selenium 0.1, ruby 1.9.2, and selenium-webdriver 2.5.0

My code is

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox;
driver.get login_url

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 2)

wait.until {
    driver.find_element(:name => 'j_password')
}

driver.find_element(:name => 'j_username').send_keys(username)

driver.focus(:name => 'j_username')`
```

and it says that `focus()` is not defined. How should I modify my code to put the input element on screen?

Um, this is a hypothetical example, I really need to scroll so that some other element is on the screen, but for simplicity I would like to be able to scroll s.t. *any* element is on the screen, even

Comment: selenium should automatically scroll down to the element. If it says it is not displayed, it usually means the element itself is not visible to the user. Double check that you are selecting the right element and that it is displayed! Alternatively try to test the same code on another page to figure out if the error is from the page or the code.

Comment: yes, you`re right... I wrote a test case an indeed, Selenium::WebDriver scrolls automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the documentation says "not visible" it's not refering the view port, but to the status of the element on the page. If something is hidden with CSS it cannot be clicked.

Answer (score 8):

`location_once_scrolled_into_view` to scroll using ruby.
As per your question your element is not visible, so selenium web driver is unable to click on it.

Simple solution to this is:

1. Store the xpath of the element which is visible and nearby to your element.
2. Scroll till that visible element, to make your element visible.
3. Ensure your element is now visible, click on it

eg code:

```
  element = dirver.find_element(:xpath, "xpath of nearby visible element")
  element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
  my_element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "xpath of your element")
  my_element.click
```

Comment: You have mispelled "driver" (dirver)

Answer (score 2):

I had an element at the bottom of the page with no other element close enough to select first. Finally got around it by tabbing from the last field in the form on the page.

element.send_keys(:tab)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll on the firefox window using **selenium webdriver**, one of the way is to use javaScript in the java code, The javeScript code to scroll down is as follows:

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight," +
                        "document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
```

I'm not aware of ruby but the above code can be used as a java Script which will scroll down the whole page.You can even define the area you want to scroll in the view window by simply hard- coding the `window.scrollTo(200,350);`