# How can I scroll to the bottom using Selenium Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have a test where I'd like to scroll to the end of the page, in order to assert something.
How can I implement this using selenium and ruby? Is there something I can add to this "particular" test where I can scroll to the bottom?

Comment: There is a method called `location_once_scrolled_into_view` as mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160999/how-to-scroll-down-to-bottom-using-selenium-in-ruby , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327858/how-to-scroll-with-selenium , https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Executing the script

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

will scroll the window to the bottom of the page.